# Calculate if a beam of light will pass through a given point?

Tags: reflection, laser, distance

I'm not sure this should be in math or physics so i'm asking in both.

Given a laser beam at closed reflective surface where point $(x,y)$ being the source of a laser bean which hits a reflective surface at $(x1,y1)$ , how can i (if possible) tell the beam will hit point $(x2,y2)$ at some point??

where the value of $x,y,,x1,y1$ is given.

**note:** the beam could hit the point after multiple reflection as well.

[image: reflective Box]

Comment: The usual framing for this problem (particularly if you want to raise this with mathematicians) is as a [billiards](https://m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards) problem.

Comment: [Cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/744375) is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Sandejo like i said , i'am not sure where this question fit's hence i posted them at both the place , once i get an answer i will delete it from the other place

Answer (score 0):

Mirror the point (x2,y2) at the surface, then draw the line from (x,y) to the mirror point .  you find the point on the surface the beam crosses and connect to (x2,y2)
I hope you see the equal angles.

Comment: isn't that valid only for a single reflection?

Comment: of cause it is, but you can co the mirroring at any of the four surfaces  and mirror the mitrror point and come up with the result depending on the initial  direction

Comment: i'm confused here